# combine rows based on duplicate in column, IF other columns has NA value

Tags: r

Ive been trying to figure out a difficult question (at least for me :D). I would like to select and combine certain rows if it meets a certain condition. I will try to explain as clear as possible.

Here a tibble of my dataset

```
# A tibble: 59,151 x 5 (df1)
   Inschrijfdatum Uitschrijfdatum inschrijf_first inschrijf_last Dup_N
   <date>         <date>          <date>          <date>         <int>
 1 2013-09-24     2022-01-01      2013-10-01      2019-04-01        19
 2 2019-08-26     2022-01-01      2019-10-01      2020-10-01        19
 3 2005-08-11     2022-01-01      2006-01-01      2020-10-01        37
 4 1992-07-15     2005-08-11      NA              NA                37
 5 1995-01-27     2022-01-01      2011-04-01      2020-10-01       106
 6 1995-07-19     2007-12-19      NA              NA               106
 7 2008-04-04     2022-01-01      NA              NA               109
 8 2018-10-31     2022-01-01      NA              NA               109
 9 1993-04-01     1996-12-31      NA              NA               129
10 1998-10-22     2005-02-23      NA              NA               129

df1 <- structure(list(Inschrijfdatum = structure(c(15972, 18134, 13006, 
8231, 9157, 9330, 13973, 17835, 8491, 10521, 7084, 11933, 16504, 
17337, 12373), class = "Date"), Uitschrijfdatum = structure(c(18993, 
18993, 18993, 13006, 18993, 13866, 18993, 18993, 9861, 12837, 
13147, 18993, 18993, 18993, 13859), class = "Date"), inschrijf_first = structure(c(15979, 
18170, 13149, NA, 15065, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 16344, NA, 17348, 
NA), class = "Date"), inschrijf_last = structure(c(17987, 18536, 
18536, NA, 18536, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18536, NA, 18536, NA
), class = "Date"), Dup_N = c(19L, 19L, 37L, 37L, 106L, 106L, 
109L, 109L, 129L, 129L, 174L, 174L, 175L, 175L, 180L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# A tibble: 20 x 5 (df2)
   Inschrijfdatum Uitschrijfdatum inschrijf_first inschrijf_last Dup_N
   <date>         <date>          <date>          <date>         <int>
 3 2019-08-28     2022-01-01      2019-10-01      2020-01-01       501
 4 2020-04-14     2022-01-01      2020-07-01      2020-10-01       501
 5 2001-06-29     2022-01-01      2014-07-01      2020-07-01       557
 6 2020-09-22     2022-01-01      2020-10-01      NA               557
 7 2013-08-30     2022-01-01      2014-01-01      2020-10-01       661
 8 2012-01-11     2013-09-01      2013-01-01      2013-07-01       661
 9 1999-09-01     2015-03-31      2006-01-01      2015-01-01       975
10 2018-04-18     2022-01-01      2018-07-01      2020-10-01       975
11 2015-05-12     2016-02-29      2015-07-01      2016-01-01      1067
12 2016-09-02     2022-01-01      2016-10-01      2020-10-01      1067
13 2014-03-03     2014-05-27      2014-04-01      NA              1079
14 2014-04-11     2016-02-18      2014-07-01      2016-01-01      1079
15 1996-09-30     2022-01-01      2006-01-01      2016-04-01      1195
16 2015-10-21     2016-01-19      2012-07-01      2016-01-01      1195



df2 <- structure(list(Inschrijfdatum = structure(c(15972, 18134, 18136, 
18366, 11502, 18527, 15947, 15350, 10835, 17639, 16567, 17046, 
16132, 16171, 9769, 16729, 13397, 18520, 16001, 16778), class = "Date"), 
    Uitschrijfdatum = structure(c(18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 
    18993, 18993, 18993, 15949, 16525, 18993, 16860, 18993, 16217, 
    16849, 18993, 16819, 16465, 18993, 16779, 18993), class = "Date"), 
    inschrijf_first = structure(c(15979, 18170, 18170, 18444, 
    16252, 18536, 16071, 15706, 13149, 17713, 16617, 17075, 16161, 
    16252, 13149, 15522, 16071, 18536, 16071, 16801), class = "Date"), 
    inschrijf_last = structure(c(17987, 18536, 18262, 18536, 
    18444, NA, 18536, 15887, 16436, 18536, 16801, 18536, NA, 
    16801, 16892, 16801, 16436, NA, 16709, 18536), class = "Date"), 
    Dup_N = c(19L, 19L, 501L, 501L, 557L, 557L, 661L, 661L, 975L, 
    975L, 1067L, 1067L, 1079L, 1079L, 1195L, 1195L, 1352L, 1352L, 
    1355L, 1355L)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I would like to do the following:

1. Identify the duplicates in Dup_N
2. Check the duplicate pair rows for Inschrijf_first & Inschrijf_last for NA value.
3. Check for NA:

- 3.1 If no NA (so both rows contain dates) -> keep separate rows & check whether these dates overlap or not

  ```
  3.1.1: If dates dont overlap (like for Dup_N=19) -> combine rows

  3.1.2: If they do overlap -> keep separated.
  ```
- 3.2 If one row NA -> combine rows
- 3.3 If both rows NA -> combine rows

If 3.2 or 3.3: combine rows(choose earliest date for Inschrijfdatum and last date for Uitschrijfdatum)

I would like to have the expected output like this:

```
Inschrijfdatum Uitschrijfdatum inschrijf_first inschrijf_last Dup_N
   <date>         <date>          <date>          <date>         <int>
 1 2013-09-24     2022-01-01      2013-10-01      2020-10-01        19
 2 1992-07-15     2022-01-01      2006-01-01      2020-10-01        37
 3 1995-01-27     2022-01-01      2011-04-01      2020-10-01       106
 4 2008-04-04     2022-01-01      NA              NA               109
 5 1993-04-01     2005-02-23      NA              NA               129
 6 1996-09-30     2022-01-01      2006-01-01      2016-04-01      1195
 7 2015-10-21     2016-01-19      2012-07-01      2016-01-01      1195
```

I think i can do step 1 and 4 with the following:

```
  group_by(Dup_N) %>%
  mutate(Inschrijfdatum = min(Inschrijfdatum), Uitschrijfdatum = max(Uitschrijfdatum))%>%
  ungroup()
```

However i struggle with the steps in between: how can i implement steps 2 and 3? I hope the question is clear now, otherwise please let me know and i will edit the question again!

Thank everybody who already helped with editting the question! And thanks again in advance! Kind regards

Comment: Would you mind adding the expected output for your sample data?

Comment: Hi Maël, thank you for your reaction! i've added a sample of expected output. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```r
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Dup_N) %>% 
  mutate(lag = any(inschrijf_first < lag(inschrijf_last)),
         cumsum = cumsum(lag)) %>% 
  group_by(Dup_N,cumsum) %>% 
  summarise(Inschrijfdatum = min(Inschrijfdatum),
            Uitschrijfdatum = max(Uitschrijfdatum), 
            inschrijf_first  = min(inschrijf_first, na.rm = T), 
            inschrijf_last = max(inschrijf_last, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  select(-cumsum)

  Dup_N Inschrijfdatum Uitschrijfdatum inschrijf_first inschrijf_last
  <int> <date>         <date>          <date>          <date>        
1    19 2013-09-24     2022-01-01      2013-10-01      2020-10-01    
2    37 1992-07-15     2022-01-01      2006-01-01      2020-10-01    
3   106 1995-01-27     2022-01-01      2011-04-01      2020-10-01    
4   109 2008-04-04     2022-01-01      NA              NA            
5   129 1993-04-01     2005-02-23      NA              NA            
6   174 1989-05-25     2022-01-01      2014-10-01      2020-10-01    
7   175 2015-03-10     2022-01-01      2017-07-01      2020-10-01    
8   180 2003-11-17     2007-12-12      NA              NA
```

You'll get warnings, but they don't affect the results.

Comment: Thank you Maël! Yes this works! However, I'm afraid that this code does not take into account that when the dates of 'inschrijf_first/inschrijf_last' of 2 (dupN duplicate) rows overlap they keep the rows separate?

Comment: I've added some extra data to show you what i mean. There are (some) rows, such as DupN 1195 in which de inschrijf_first/last dates overlap (this is a period of time). If this is the case i would like to keep the rows separated.

Comment: See my update, you can create another column that detect if dates overlap and create a new group which will allow to keep the rows separated.

Comment: you can add them in group_by (or take everything minus the variables you don't want)

Comment: Hi Maël, thanks again! On further inspection of the data i notice that some Dup N duplicates, which do not have overlapping inschrijf_first and inschrijf_last dates are kept separated instead of combined. Do you maybe have an idea how this is possible?

Comment: I have no idea. You can ask a separate question for that matter.